Sql query group and sum
I would like to calculate Daytime energy per month.
In Estonia, daytime energy is Monday to Friday 6:00 - 22:00.
I have a database where I save data every minute.



AEG
KWHI1




2024-05-13 07:55:00
5896.204


2024-05-13 07:54:00
5896.186


2024-05-13 07:53:00
5896.163


2024-05-13 07:52:00
5896.160


2024-05-13 07:51:00
5896.160



SELECT
    `AEG`,
    MAX(KWHI1) - MIN(KWHI1) AS OST
FROM
    `LOGPV`
WHERE
    `AEG` BETWEEN "2024.04.1" AND "2024.04.30" AND(HOUR(`AEG`) BETWEEN 7 AND 21) AND(WEEKDAY(`AEG`) +1 BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
GROUP BY
    DAY(`AEG`)

and this answer:



AEG
OST




2024-04-01 07:00:26
1.456


2024-04-02 07:00:11
11.296


2024-04-03 07:00:25
3.718


2024-04-26 07:00:00
1.617


2024-04-29 07:00:00
1.177



How to sum the OST?
1.456+11.296+3.718+.....+1.617+1.177=107.874 kWh Daytime energy Apr.

You do not need "to sum the OST". Simply substract w/o GROUP BY.

And your SELECT clause should have DAY(AEG), not just AEG

That MySQL doesn't throw an error on your invalid query is a bad sign. You are probably using an old MySQL version without having set sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. Make sure you have always set this mode when working with MySQL in order to be warned when writing invalid group by queries.  Double quotes are name delimiters in SQL by the way, not string delimiters. And you should use date literals instead of string literals anyway. Date literals look like this: DATE '2024-04-01'.

If you wish to sum the daily OST values by month, the following will do the job:
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT
      DATE(AEG) AS AEGDate,
      MAX(KWHI1) - MIN(KWHI1) AS OST
  FROM
      LOGPV
  WHERE
      (HOUR(AEG) BETWEEN 7 AND 21) AND(WEEKDAY(AEG) +1 BETWEEN 1 AND 5)
  GROUP BY
      DATE(AEG)
)
SELECT 
    MONTH(AEGDate) AS Month,
    SUM(OST) AS TotalOST
FROM cte
GROUP BY Month


But how can I get an all month energy and night energy
TOTAL - DAY = NIGHT         and table:
MONTH /  DAY  /  NIGHT  /  TOTAL
